# Job listing title shouldn't be clickable as it goes no where

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

After you find a job and click on it you are taken to the job listing page.
The page's job title is a hyperlink but I'm not sure why.  It doesn't even seem to serve as an anchor on the job page.

Here's what I mean...

1. Go to any job like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/101707/software-engineer-net-quicken-loans
2. Hover over the title, in this example Software Engineer.
3. Notice that it is a link
4. Click the link and notice no change / redirection

Please eliminate this as a hyperlink:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is identical to how [the title on every question links to the canonical URL for that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47653/why-does-the-question-title-link-to-itself-on-the-answer-page).

It's both a convenient way to grab the URL and a fairly common convention; I wouldn't mess with it.